# Microsoft.AspNet.OData: URL encoded search value in $filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

We're using Microsoft.AspNet.OData, and our controllers look like this:

```
namespace Backend.api.Process
{
    public class OdataProcessController: ODataController
    {
        private readonly IProcessService _service;

        public OdataProcessController(IProcessService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(_service.GetAllProcesses());
        }
    }
}
```

However, some of our processes have names that include special characters (like "&"), which have to be URLencoded before being sent backend when searching. It does not seem like the ASP.Net Odata framework automatically handles this. Therefore, my task is now to ensure the search string is decoded backend.

I've looked into extending the endpoint to accept ODataQueryOptions (see below), but I can't figure out how to change the filter string and rewrapping it back into an ODataQueryOptions object:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<ProcessModel> queryOptions)
    {
        var allProcesses= _service.GetAllProcesses();
        queryOptions.ApplyTo(allProcesses);
        return Ok(allProcesses);
    }
```

Is my only option to rewrite my service function to accept the filter parameter and implement the filtering myself?

Comment: if i understood you correctly, you should create a new HttpRequestMessage to apply . Build your string with filter querystrings and create a new HttpRequestMessage.

[You can ref here](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/33660648/odata-v4-modify--filter-on-server-side)

Answer (score 0):

The link Erdem provided gave me the answer, which was to create an attribute class to override the OnActionExecuting function:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace Backend.api.Process
{
    public class DecodeFilter : EnableQueryAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var url = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.OriginalString;
            var newUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);

            actionContext.Request.RequestUri = new Uri(newUrl);
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

and then using it as follows:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    [DecodeFilter]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_service.GetAllProcesses());
    }
```